# Caching node_modules in Azure Pipelines takes longer than installing them

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-caching, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I am running a self-hosted agent (Windows Server) and I am trying to reduce my pipeline build time by caching my node_modules. However, restoring the node_modules cache takes just as long as installing the packages from scratch. Also, looking at the log it gives me the impression that it is downloading/uploading the cache externally, rather than keeping the cache on the VM. If this is true, then my caching of the node_modules would result in transferring ~1GB of data on every build.

What am I doing wrong?

My goal is to simply maintain/keep the node_modules between builds on my self-hosted agent for the following reasons:

1. To prevent installing the node_modules everytime
2. To keep the node_modules/.cache folder for [computational caching](https://blog.nrwl.io/computation-caching-out-of-the-box-revamped-docs-community-plugins-and-more-in-nx-9-2-e97801116e02) purposes

[image]

#### My Pipeline YML File:

```yaml
trigger:
  - develop
  - master

variables:
  nodeModulesCache: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/node_modules

stages:
  - stage: client_qa
    displayName: Client code QA
    dependsOn: []
    pool:
      name: Default
    jobs:
      - job:
        displayName: Lint & test client code
        steps:
          # Use NodeJS.
          - task: UseNode@1
            inputs:
              version: "12.x"

          # Restore cache.
          - task: Cache@2
            inputs:
              key: 'npm | "$(Agent.OS)" | client/package-lock.json'
              restoreKeys: |
                npm | "$(Agent.OS)"
              path: $(nodeModulesCache)
            displayName: Cache Node modules

          # Install dependencies.
          - script: npm install
            workingDirectory: client
            displayName: "Install packages"

          # Lint affected code.
          - script: npm run lint:affected:ci
            workingDirectory: client
            displayName: "Lint affected code"

          # Test affected code.
          - script: npm run test:affected:ci
            workingDirectory: client
            displayName: "Run affected unit tests"
```

Comment: i saw this with Python as well, best to use a your own Docker image

Comment: Hi @Rusty, Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if you have any questions. If the answer could help, you may consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). Thanks.

Comment: Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: @VitoLiu-MSFT, yes your suggestion of using `- checkout: self clean: false` solved the issue for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cache the `node_modules` to `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/node_modules`, the path should be `_\agent_work\1\s\node_modules`. The self-hosted agent will run `execute git clean -ffdx && git reset --hard HEAD` before fetching, it will delete the folder `node_modules` and install the `node_modules` everytime.  check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps-checkout?view=azure-pipelines) for more details.

We need add the code `- checkout: self clean: false` at the steps level.

YAML definition

```yaml
trigger:
  - develop
  - master

variables:
  nodeModulesCache: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/node_modules

stages:
  - stage: client_qa
    displayName: Client code QA
    dependsOn: []
    pool:
      name: Default
    jobs:
      - job:
        displayName: Lint & test client code
        steps:
          - checkout: self
            clean: false 
          # Use NodeJS.
          - task: UseNode@1
            inputs:
              version: "12.x"

          # Restore cache.
          - task: Cache@2
            inputs:
              key: 'npm | "$(Agent.OS)" | client/package-lock.json'
              restoreKeys: |
                npm | "$(Agent.OS)"
              path: $(nodeModulesCache)
            displayName: Cache Node modules

          # Install dependencies.
          - script: npm install
            workingDirectory: client
            displayName: "Install packages"

          # Lint affected code.
          - script: npm run lint:affected:ci
            workingDirectory: client
            displayName: "Lint affected code"

          # Test affected code.
          - script: npm run test:affected:ci
            workingDirectory: client
            displayName: "Run affected unit tests"
```

Comment: In my case the "clean" option worked well removing the task of "Restore cache". This task is no more needed, in my case it made me only lost time to download and restore a node_modules already present.

Comment: @VitoLiu-MSFT - Is the correct variable then `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\node_modules` to use?